# How does a child controller access its parent controller in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have some properties on my parent controller that I want my child controller to have access to.

I want to access it like so:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    prop1: "someProp",
    prop2: "someotherProp",
    needs: ["child"]
});

App.ChildController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    prop1: Ember.computed.alias("parentController.prop1"),
    prop2: Ember.computed.alias("parentController.prop2"),
});
```

How do I access those properties?

--edit---
Does it assume there will always be a single instance of the controller I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access something in the needs array you use this.get('controllers.some_controller'). I think the above is slightly backwards as you want the child to have access to the application controller.

```
App.ChildController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application']
    prop1: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.prop1"),
    prop2: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.prop2"),
});
```

Comment: Does it assume there will always be a single instance of the controller I need?

Comment: Computed.alias is a two way binding unless you set it to be read only. Controllers are almost always singletons unless you jump through some hoops to instantiate several.